# Validate form while type and submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a contact form in cf7 with this js code:

```
const form = document.querySelector(".wpcf7-form");

  let username = form.elements.namedItem("your-name");

  username.addEventListener("input", validate);

  function validate(e) {
    if (e.target.name == "your-name") {
      if (e.target.value.length > 3) {
        e.target.classList.remove("wpcf7-not-valid");
        e.target.setAttribute("aria-invalid", "false");
      } else {
        e.target.classList.add("wpcf7-not-valid");
        e.target.setAttribute("aria-invalid", "true");
      }
    }
  }
```

The issue is when i press button submit cf7 checks the input "`your-name`" and if its not empty then change `aria-invalid="true"` for `aria-invalid="false"` and send the form.

My goal is if the input field has less than 4 letters, `aria-invalid="true"` (its working), and when i press submit dont change for `aria-invalid="false"` (this is not working, when u press submit cf7 checks input field is not empty and it change `aria-invalid="false"`)

Answer (score 0):

you can call the same input event on submitting the form using `dispatchEvent(event)` method

```js
const form = document.querySelector(".wpcf7-form");

  let username = form.elements.namedItem("your-name");

  username.addEventListener("input", validate);

  function validate(e) {
    if (e.target.name == "your-name") {
      if (e.target.value.length > 3) {
        e.target.classList.remove("wpcf7-not-valid");
        e.target.setAttribute("aria-invalid", "false");
      } else {
        e.target.classList.add("wpcf7-not-valid");
        e.target.setAttribute("aria-invalid", "true");
      }
    }
  }
  
  document.querySelector('.wpcf7-form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    console.log("called");
    var event = new Event('input');
    username.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```html
<form class="wpcf7-form" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="your-name"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

Comment: Thx so much! Its possible use `document.querySelector(".wpcf7-form")` instead `document.getElementById('form1')`. Because i want to target all forms. I am trying but doesnt work (my method with `querySelector`)

Comment: Thx, but i want to use the class instead the id `document.querySelector('.form1')` but doesnt work